# Do test accounts require real credit card to purchase via In-app Billing?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

Inching slowly (but methodically) towards my first implementation of In-app Billing, I reached the point in which I can actually run the [market billing sample application](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-download): The app is signed and uploaded to the [AM](https://market.android.com/), the "product list" has been created per the [instructions](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-download) and a test account has been set in both Google *and* the phone.

But when I proceed (successfully) with a purchase, despite selecting the test account on the [AM](https://market.android.com/), I am prompted to confirm the purchase with my real gmail account, to which my real credit card is linked.

When testing PayPal, for example, one can create test accounts, too, with fake CC numbers, to test freely w/o burdening the real CC system.

Is this available (or possible) for In-app Billing development & testing, too?

**Update:** I tested this on a different device, having only the test account set, and sure enough the Android Market behaves erroneously, responding the following error message:

> The item you were attempting to purchase could not be found.

[image]

I know that the item is there and that it is set up properly in the Android Market because this error is never issued on the device with the real account with the CC number (there I receive a perfect behavior with the masked CC number, the Total and an `Accept & buy` button). Why does Google write such misleading error messages?

**Update:** I found [this incredible thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763377/testing-android-market-in-app-billing-with-dummy-credit-card-credentials), which seems to partially answer my question. Unless something new has been introduced by Google since then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use a real credit card. However, you can always refund your test purchases!

Note that you'll have to make the purchases from a test account that's separate from your developer account, since Google Checkout doesn't allow an account to buy from itself.

Comment: Using a real credit card then refund purchases can be done with any account, why do I need a **test** account then? What is the difference between a "test account" and regular account? Can the test account use the same credit card of the master (developer/merchant) account? +1 for now.

Comment: The difference is that the test account can see the in app purchase on an un-published app, where as the other (non test accounts) cannot see the app (because it is not published). Additionally the developer account cannot buy items from itself (as Bruno mentioned above).

Comment: @BillTheApe i am testing this inapp now i want to refund then how can i refund it?

Comment: I think @Syntax has a good point on that but since the In-App documentation states this: "When purchases are complete, Google Play prevents the orders from going to financial processing, ensuring that there are no actual charges to user accounts, and automatically canceling the completed orders after 14 days". I can't see any reasons to refund given the fact that it wasn't processed.

Comment: Is it still true that a real credit card has to be used even for test purchases? Also, what is the logic behind this, to use real credit cards in a sandbox environment?

Answer (score 1):

Test accounts are useful when you upload your application as a draft application,not published.Then using test account you can do even purchase of unpublished application.Hope this helps.