# Credit card for Google Play test

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I don't want to input my credit card for Google Play test. Is there any way I can do this like what we did in iOS IAP testing?

Or is it possible to create Redeem code for testing?

The reason is I'm not feeling comfortable to add my Credit Card number. One of my friends once was stolen about $600 through Google wallet (although Google paid him back later).

Another bad case is my another friend received the bill from his Credit Card company to pay for the testing of Google Play's In App Billing although Google said it's safe to do so.(He told me he even saw "This is a test order, you will not be charged" when he did testing)

Thanks

Comment: To my knowledge, that's not possible. You could always buy a $20 Visa gift card. And if testing the credit card number input itself is not that important, you could also buy yourself a Google Wallet Gift card.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll consider that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Testing Android Market in-app billing with dummy credit card credentials](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763377/testing-android-market-in-app-billing-with-dummy-credit-card-credentials)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think he was talking about the Google Play's In App Billing. So I don't think it's possible to use sandbox for testing.

Comment: Yes. It's for IAB. I did mention iOS IAP.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the documentation here. It will give you access to a group that will automatically input test cards into your current google account you're using within the sandbox https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/resources/test-card-suite